# Android точка доступа, получить ip адрес подключённых устройств

Tags: android, c++, kotlin, http, esp8266

Есть **ESP8266** который подключается к телефону на **Android**. На телефоне точка доступа **WI-FI**, **ESP** является **HTTP** сервером.
Мне необходимо программно получить **IP** адрес подключённого устройства, чтобы отправлять **HTTP** запросы. На данный момент я могу узнать **IP** адрес **ESP** из монитора порта или на телефоне в параметрах точки доступа, но когда начал тестировать на телефонах **Xiaomi**, возможности посмотреть **IP** в настройках нет, только сторонний софт.
Планирую организовать подключение нескольких устройств к телефону и их отсортировывать по **IP** или именам.
Подскажите пожалуйста как это реализовать или может использовать другой протокол для связи с телефоном

Comment: Наверное тут нужен DNS .

Comment: Ну, можно заморочиться, подключить к esp какой-нибудь экран, чтобы он сам выводил свой ip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

решил проблему с помощью создания на андроид сервера io.ktor, который принимает запрос от есп с его ip адресом с которым можно дальше работать